# Import data from Internet to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there anyway that I could import the data (csv file) directly from the internet to SQL Server 2008?

Or must I download the file to the computer first, then import later?

Comment: You need to download the file first, then do a e.g. bulk insert into SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't import CSV file into SQLServer from URLs as source, the only valid path are:

- local path from the server on which SQLServer is running

  ```
  BULK INSERT CsvTable FROM 'C:\CsvFile.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
  ```
- a remote file, specify the UNC name

  ```
  BULK INSERT CsvTable FROM '\\ServerName\ShareName\Path\CsvFile.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
  ```